# Android NDK: Set Field from C

Tags: java, c, get, android-ndk, set

I have a native  opensl audio callback. I want to extract the dB of each buffer and set the GLRenderer scalematrix in order to create a simple vumeter in java. I'm trying to get a static setter method id, a static field id, also tried with non-static:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
 JNIEnv* env;
 if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
  return -1;

 globalMyNativeActivityClass = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/tremolofx/vumeterGLRenderer"));

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI_OnLoad", "FindClass-> %p",       globalMyNativeActivityClass);
setAmp = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, globalMyNativeActivityClass, "setAmp", "(F)V");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI_OnLoad",
"GetMethodID -> %p", setAmp);
//  (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, obj, setAmp, 20.0);
fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,globalMyNativeActivityClass,"amp","F");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI_OnLoad",
"GetStaticFieldID -> %p", fid);

return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
 }
```

So this code is getting not null class, method and field. Now I want to set the field via the setter or changing its value directly, cause my glrenderer is rendering constinously.Something like that:

```
 void setVumeter( jfloat dB){
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "opensl_stream", "1");



     (*env)->CallVoidStaticMethod(...notclearstuff.. ,setAmp, dB); 



          }
```

and call to this at the end of my native audio callback. I tried all on the internet, but the app crashes always in the call or the set and I'm going crazy.

```
        Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 7154
```

Comment: Hello there! Good question. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak . You'll see that deadd00d means that the Dalvik VM aborted. Often there'll be something else in your logcat indicating why (not necessarily under your app's package name). When debugging deadd00d, the first place to start looking is in that logcat in case there's anything interesting!

Comment: And, if so post it here of course!